# Simulating a Stochastic Process within certain bounds

Tags: simulation

I would like to simulate paths of a Geometric Brownian Motion till it hits one of two barriers, say 10 or 200.

```
data2 = RandomFunction[
  GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[0.05, .15, 100], {0, 10, .01}, 1]
ListLinePlot[data2]
```

[image]

```
data3 = %69["Path"]

data4 = {}

j = 1; While[data3[[j, 2]] < 200 && data3[[j, 2]] > 10, 
 data4 = Append[data4, {data3[[j, 1]], data3[[j, 2]]}]; j++]

ListLinePlot[data4]
```

[image]

This works but is clunky and inelegant. Is there someway I can do it better or maybe run the simulation till some barrier is hit instead of truncating the data post simulation?

Comment: Please don't use `%69` — your `%69` is not the same for anyone else and they will not be able to run it (also, I save only 1 previous output)...

Comment: No time to try this, but I wonder if Rescale or RescalingTransform might help?

Comment: @rm-rf I have no clue what %69 even is. When I Shift Enter data2, MMA-9 prints: Temporaldata[1]. Then MMA-9 gives this window right below Temporaldata[1]. That window gave a drop down menu called properties which had path as an option. When I clicked on path, it ran the command %69["path"] and spat out the data. So I just re-used that command to catch that data. The documentation for % doesn't explain what it is so perhaps you can shed some light on it.

Comment: @Amatya `%` is the previous input, `%%` 2 inputs prior,  `%n` n inputs prior (all, as indicated by the `In[n]` and not by your current position)

Comment: To be slightly more precise: `%n` is the nth input not n inputs before current.

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks, I did know about the % command but with the ["path"] stuff following it, I figured %69 meant something else, especially since all this was early in the notebook.. but I also had other notebooks active.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not aware of possibilities to set up `RandomFunction` with barriers. However, your after-the-fact selection of data can be done somewhat more elegantly indeed:

```
data4 = TakeWhile[data3, 10 < #[[2]] < 200 &];
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't manage to make it work with `RandomFunction`, but if you would consider running simulations without it you could use `TruncatedDistribution`.

Define the parameters :

```
mu = 5/100; sigma = 15/100; x0 = 100;

xmin = 80; xmax = 200;

tmin = 1/100; tmax = 10; dt = 1/100;
```

Define the truncated distribution :

```
trDist[xmin_, xmax_, mu_, sigma_, x0_, t_] := TruncatedDistribution[{xmin, xmax}, 
   LogNormalDistribution[Log[x0] + (mu - 1/2 sigma^2) t, sigma Sqrt[t]]]

d = Transpose[RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[Log[x0] + (mu - 1/2 sigma^2) #, 
   sigma Sqrt[#]], 2] & /@ Range[tmin, tmax, dt]];
paths = Transpose[{Range[tmin, tmax, dt], #}] & /@ d;

d2 = Transpose[RandomVariate[trDist[xmin,xmax,mu,sigma,x0,#], 2] & /@ Range[tmin,tmax,dt]];
paths2 = Transpose[{Range[tmin, tmax, dt], #}] & /@ d2;
```

Check :

```
ListLinePlot[paths, PlotRange -> {0, All}, Epilog -> {Black, Line[{{tmin, xmin}, {tmax, xmin}}], Line[{{tmin, xmax}, {tmax, xmax}}]}]
```

[image: without]

```
ListLinePlot[paths2, PlotRange -> {0, All}, Epilog -> {Black, Line[{{tmin, xmin}, {tmax, xmin}}], Line[{{tmin, xmax}, {tmax, xmax}}]}]
```

[image: with]